# Find all stationary points for $f(x,y,z)=(x+xy+yz)e^x.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have that

\begin{array}{lcl}
f'_{x} & = & (1+x+y+xy+yz)e^x \\
f'_{y} & = & (x+z)e^x \\
f'_{z} & = & ye^x
\end{array}

Solving all these partials, simultaneously equal to zero I get that there exists only one statinary point that is $(x,y,z)=(-1,0,1).$ Now I want to determine the nature of this point by examining the quadratic form $Q(h,k,l).$ For the second derivatives I have

\begin{array}{lcl}
f''_{xx} & = & (2+2y+x+xy+yz)e^x \\
f''_{yy} & = & 0 \\
f''_{zz} & = & 0 \\
f''_{xy} & = & (1+x+z)e^x \\
f''_{yz} & = & e^x \\
f''_{xz} & = & ye^x \\
\end{array}

Which gives

\begin{array}{lcl}
Q(h,k,l) & = & f''_{xx}(-1,0,1)h^2+f''_{yy}(-1,0,1)k^2+f''_{zz}(-1,0,1)l^2 +\\
         & + & 2f''_{xy}(-1,0,1)hk +2f''_{yz}(-1,0,1)hl+2f''_{xz}(-1,0,1)kl \\
         & = & \frac{1}{e}h^2+\frac{2}{e}hk+\frac{2}{e}hl=\frac{1}{e}(h^2+2hk+2hl).
\end{array}

Using the trinomial squared rule I can rewrite the last equality as

$$\frac{1}{e}\left[(h+k+l)^2-k^2-l^2-2kl\right]=\frac{1}{e}\left[(h+k+l)^2-(k+l)^2\right],$$

which means that this quadratic form is *positively indefnite* since it can attain both negative and positive values which in turn implies that this is a *saddle point*.

**Question:** Am I doing this right?

Comment: I did not check the calculations but the method looks correct, you might want to find the sign of the Hessian to save time, but this looks correct also.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=saddle+points+(x%2Bx*y%2By*z)e%5Ex) confirms your finding.